# js firing only once in jquery mobile site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I have a mobile layout page that loads a js file and it works fine.

```
    @RenderBody()
    <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var moonth = $("#getcurrmonth").val();
    var yeear = $("#getcurryear").val();
    $("#hiddenyearval").val(yeear);
    $("#hiddenmonthval").val(parseInt(moonth) - 1);
    $("#caltab").collapsible("expand");
    LOCAL.LoadMore();
    LOCAL.LoadMore();
    LOCAL.LoadMore();
    $("#caltab").collapsible("collapse");
});
    </script>

    <script>
LOCAL = {
    LoadMore: function () {...}
}
    </script>

    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_Tabs.mobile.cshtml")
```

But when I change to a page that uses the same layout the script never fires.

I have tried $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '[data-role="page"]', function{..} as well as other suggestions I have found on here but no luck.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hi, maybe your problem is because jQuery mobile usea cache for the pages, look here: https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-cache.html at the bottom in Caching pages in the DOM

Comment: I tried to toggle the  data-dom-cache="true" setting but no change

Comment: Ouch, another idea is that review the html that you have, remember that a page in jQueryMobile us a div that the attribute data-role="page", so maybe try to put the script inside this to see is the problem is for this configuration

Comment: being a caching issue I would recommend putting this code into a function and in the document.ready on each page,  call the function.